# Why is metadata not encrypted?

Tags: encryption, metadata

This is a very general question. I am working on a project with my fellow students, and we are trying to create a blockchain-based communication platform. 
One of the flaws we found in email security today, is that metadata is not encrypted.

I am finding it difficult to find an explanation of why metadata is not encrypted in the first place?

Comment: That strongly depends on what kind of metadata in what kind of file format/protocol you're talking about…

Answer (score 1):

We separate an email into these two parts:

- **The payload** (or content), which contains the actual text of the messages (or photos, or whatever you may send).
- **The metadata**, which contains the information *about the message*, but not the message itself.

Consider the metadata as being the information on an envelope. Surely, if you want to deliver a message, you have to write the recipient's address on the front of the envelope. Also, on the back you may want to write *your* address, so that the postal company (mail server) can return the message when it is not delivered. Furthermore, the postal company knows additional information. For example, they know *when* the message was sent and when it was delivered. They also know the weight of the envelope.

All in all, the *metadata* **cannot** reasonably be encrypted, because 1) it is required for the email to be delivered, or 2) because it is an property of the email itself.

If we encrypt the recipient's address, the postal company would not know where to deliver the message. Encrypting the size of a message doesn't even make sense (although we could try to obfuscate it).